# How to delete Grub Menu from the disk without Linux?

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader

How do I remove Grub Menu from the disk without Linux?
When I boot from the disc out the string Grub Rescue.
Previously, I installed Ubuntu 10.10 and randomly chose the wrong drive.

Comment: Removing grub will simply make the disk not bootable.  You probably want to replace it with something, and it helps to specify what it is you want to put in its place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot your windows disc, and repair the master boot record from the recovery menu.

Comment: If you don't have your Windows installation disc (many computers don't come with them these days), you can typically order it from the manufacturer at minimal cost. Or just burn a disc from the Windows free trial `.iso` image that you can download from Microsoft's website (you don't need to be able to install Windows, just to repair your existing system).

Comment: I have the disk container (0x05). What is it?
It contains the Grub Loader program or not?

Comment: @Leonid By "Windows disc," we mean the external CD/DVD (or USB flash drive) that you would boot from to reinstall Windows. You don't actually have to reinstall Windows, but you have to use this to reinstall the boot loader.

Comment: I had installed Ubuntu near Windows XP, but I had selected wrong disk. How to delete Grub from disk with Windows XP? Its partion, or it's file ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best and fastest option would be to download an rBoot ISO and burn it to a CD. (download via torrent)

Boot from it and select the bootable Windows partition. You will get logged into Windows.

In Windows, install EasyBCD. Open it. In the Deployment section, select write Windows 7 bootloader to MBR. Restart.

If all goes well, you'll successfully boot into Windows.